# nested horizontal collectionview in auto size tableview cell exanding height make collection view scroll reset when reload cell for row accured

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autosize

i have table view for showing product detail and each part is tableview cell,

in one of my tableview cell that is showing sizes and stores that has that size like this 
[image: like this] and [image: this]

when the user click on one of collection view items tableview expand to show stores.

if i update root tableviewcell constraints i need to reload that cell
after reloading collection scroll will rest

i tried beginUpdates and endUpdates for root tableview after changing constraint it will work but in some situation it will show a blank cell
what's wrong in my idea

in summary :
how to expand tableview cell without reloading and refresh  cell view  .i think both questions are equal

Comment: what about implementing that logic inside the collectionViewCell

Comment: collectionview cells are not full width according to images bro .

Answer (score 1):

Change the constraints in the **tableView** and add to model the currently selected collectionViewCell and scroll to it with no animation in collectionViewCell **awakeFromNib** method the default value is 0 which means no animation will happen [the model I mean here is the model of the tableView from which you display every tableViewCell]

Comment: in this design i have  to save some properties in view controller like selected collectionview item , i think its better to handle this in root tableview cell  for code clearity . there is no way to cache root tvcell ?

Comment: The model will be global so collectionViewCell click will edit it , noway to cache tvcell it's based on dequeuing strategy

Comment: by your suggesting way i need to save last scrolled frame of collection view and selected cvcell item in viewcontroller and pass it to new cell in cellforRow .i think its a dirty model 

i know dequeuing is the main problem so i need to implement a custom tableview  with scroll view :D

Comment: No , only the index [integer value] of the currently selected collectionViewCell and the related tvcell no frames it will be handled by scrolling to indexpath

Comment: thank you by the way ,i'm searching for some alternative ways

Comment: You may also replace the collectionView with a horizental UIStackView and solve the problem

Comment: there is no limited amount of cvcell may be 10 ... .
we need scrolled frame for scroll to exact same place